# CSS Grid Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-grid

When clicking on the hamburger icon, I want the dropdown menu to overlay the content below the header. At the moment, the problem is that the dropdown menu is pushing the content down instead of overlaying it. I tried fiddling with z-index and positioning but nothing seems to work.

HTML Code

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&family=Rubik:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/da53fde61e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <img src="../img/Logo.png" class="nav-logo" alt="Rockville Volleyball Academy Logo">
            <div id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
                <div class="nav-icon"></div>
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul id="nav-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Programs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tournaments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Recreation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <section class="home">

            <img src="./img/Logo.png" alt="Rockville Volleyball Academy Logo" class="home-logo">
        </section>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS Code

```
:root {
    --primary-color: #000A41;
    --secondary-color: #c62828;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: #fff;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 25% 25%;
}

/******************/
/* Navigation bar */
/******************/

nav {
    grid-column: 1 / 6;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 400ms ease;
}

nav ul:not(.active) {
    display: none;
}

nav li {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 10px 25px 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    z-index: 10;
}

nav li:hover {
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-toggle {
    grid-column: 5 / 6;
    place-self: center;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.nav-toggle.active .nav-icon {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.nav-toggle.active .nav-icon::before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-toggle.active .nav-icon::after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.nav-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 6px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.nav-icon:before,
.nav-icon:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: 400ms;
}

.nav-icon:before {
    top: -12px;
}

.nav-icon:after {
    top: 12px;
}

.nav-logo {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    place-self: center;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0.5em;
}

/******************/
/*    Home Page   */
/******************/

.home {
    display: grid;
    /* grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr; */
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 25% 25%;
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
}

.home-logo {
    grid-column: 2 / 5;
    place-self: center;
    width: 217px;
}
```

JS Code

```
var ready = (callback) => {
    if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
        callback()
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback)
    }
}

ready(() => {
    const nav_menu = document.getElementById('nav-menu')
    const nav_icon = document.getElementById('nav-toggle')

    nav_icon.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        nav_collapse()
    })


    function nav_collapse() {
        // set exit icon
        nav_icon.classList.toggle('active')

        if (!nav_menu.classList.contains('active')) {
            // display menu
            nav_menu.classList.add('active')
            nav_menu.style.height = 'auto'

            // get computed height of menu
            let height = nav_menu.clientHeight + 'px'

            // set height of menu to 0 to trigger the slide down animation
            nav_menu.style.height = '0px'

            // set 100ms delay for slide down effect
            setTimeout(() => {
                nav_menu.style.height = height
            }, 100);
        } else {
            // set height of menu to 0 to trigger the slide up animation
            nav_menu.style.height = '0px'

            // collapse menu when animation finishes
            nav_menu.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
                nav_menu.classList.remove('active')
            }, {once: true})
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you please tell me. Do you want this section part under the navigation or not?

Answer (score 1):

In this section part in displayed under the navigation and now content is not coming upon the nav

part. Can you check and tell me how you want to diplayed it and where?

```js
var ready = (callback) => {
    if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
        callback()
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback)
    }
}

ready(() => {
    const nav_menu = document.getElementById('nav-menu')
    const nav_icon = document.getElementById('nav-toggle')

    nav_icon.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        nav_collapse()
    })


    function nav_collapse() {
        // set exit icon
        nav_icon.classList.toggle('active')

        if (!nav_menu.classList.contains('active')) {
            // display menu
            nav_menu.classList.add('active')
            nav_menu.style.height = 'auto'

            // get computed height of menu
            let height = nav_menu.clientHeight + 'px'

            // set height of menu to 0 to trigger the slide down animation
            nav_menu.style.height = '0px'

            // set 100ms delay for slide down effect
            setTimeout(() => {
                nav_menu.style.height = height
            }, 100);
        } else {
            // set height of menu to 0 to trigger the slide up animation
            nav_menu.style.height = '0px'

            // collapse menu when animation finishes
            nav_menu.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
                nav_menu.classList.remove('active')
            }, {once: true})
        }
    }
})
```

```css
     :root {
    --primary-color: #000A41;
    --secondary-color: #c62828;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: #fff;
    display: grid;
}

/******************/
/* Navigation bar */
/******************/

nav {
    grid-column: 1 / 6;
    grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 400ms ease;
}

nav ul:not(.active) {
    display: none;
}

nav li {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px 10px 25px 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    z-index: 10;
}

nav li:hover {
    background-color: var(--secondary-color);
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-toggle {
    grid-column: 5 / 6;
    place-self: center;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.nav-toggle.active .nav-icon {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.nav-toggle.active .nav-icon::before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-toggle.active .nav-icon::after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.nav-icon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 6px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.nav-icon:before,
.nav-icon:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: 400ms;
}

.nav-icon:before {
    top: -12px;
}

.nav-icon:after {
    top: 12px;
}

.nav-logo {
    grid-column: 1 / 2;
    place-self: center;
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

/******************/
/*    Home Page   */
/******************/


.home-logo {
    grid-column: 2 / 5;
    place-self: center;
    width: 217px;
}
```

```html
  

   <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&family=Rubik:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/da53fde61e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
  
   <body>

      <header>
            <h2 style="margin: 25px;">RVA </h2>
            <div id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
                <div class="nav-icon"></div>
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul id="nav-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Programs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tournaments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Recreation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul> 
               
            </nav>
           
        </header>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I want the nav dropdown to overlay over the logo. When I ran the snippet, it simply pushed the logo down instead of stacking over it. Let me know if I'm not being clear, please.

Comment: ok if it is logo which is going down then what was that which is in the right side volleyball acedemy. you want this to put or it was a mistake? I can remove that image if it is not being used or i use only logo in place of this academy pic or text.

Comment: "  the right side volleyball acedemy" sorry left side image

Comment: The logo does not come down it stays fixed in the navbar. Only the menu comes down. You can use text if that makes it easier.

Comment: Check this, i use text in place of image.